Holomorphic function is zero if $f(n)=0$
This is a question from a previous exam given at IMPA. A friend of mine and myself spent the afternoon  attempting this with great effort. Maybe we overlooked some simpler more canonical approach, but we ended up solving this nevertheless:

Let $f$ be a bounded holomorphic function on $\{z ∈ \mathbb{C} | Re(z) > 0\}$. Suppose
that $f(n) = 0$ for all $n ∈ \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Prove that $f = 0$.

Define:
$$H_n(z)=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{z-k}{z+k}$$
Clearly, $F_n(z)=\frac{f(z)}{H_n(z)}$ is holomorphic. Furthermore, $|F_n(z)|\leq \frac{M}{|H_n(z)|}$. It is also clear that on a large enough circle of radious $R$ (intercepted with the right plane) it holds that:
$$|H_n(z)|\geq\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{R-k}{R+k}>1-\varepsilon$$
By the Maximum Modulus principle (applied for the right plane-actually the same usual proof applies considering the mean integral), inside the unit circle it holds that:
$$|F_n(z)|\leq \frac{M}{1-\varepsilon}$$
However, our bound for $H_n(z)$ also holds outside of the circle, so for every $z$ in our domain it holds that $|F_n(z)|\leq M/(1-\varepsilon)$. Actually, because $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary we may do much better and write $|F_n(z)|\leq M$. By the identity theorem it is enough to prove that  $f$ is not identically zero on $(1/2,1)\subset \mathbb{R}$. Suppose by way of contradiction there is a point in the real axis $x\in (1/2,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)|\not=0$. Of course $x\not\in \mathbb{N}$ and:
$$|F_n(x)|=\left|f(x)\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{x+k}{x-k}\right|$$
Also, $\frac{x+k}{x-k}=1+\frac{2k}{x-k}$ Also, for our $x$ it holds that $\frac{2k}{k-x}>\frac{2k}{k-1/2}=\frac{4k}{2k-1}=2+\frac{2}{2k-1}$. This implies $\frac{x+k}{x-k}<-2-\frac{2}{2k-1}+1$ and $\frac{x+k}{k-x}>1+\frac{2}{2k-1}$. Hence:
$$ M\geq |F_n(x)|\geq \left| f(x)\prod_{k=1}^{n }\frac{x-k}{x+k}\right|\geq |f(x)| \prod_{k=1}^{n }\left(1+\frac{2}{2k-1}\right) $$
Using Bernoulli's generalized inequality:
$$M\geq |f(x)|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2}{2k-1}\geq |f(x)|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$$
This holds for every large $n$, which is clearly a contradiction with the uniform bound $M$.

an easy proof is to translate everything to the unit disc by $w=\frac{z-1}{z+1}$; then $n \to w_n=1-\frac{2}{n+1}$ and $f$ goes to a bounded holomorphic function $F$ on the unit disc with zeroes at $w_n$ for which $\sum (1-|w_n|)=\infty$ hence $F$ must be zero by a simple application of Jensen theorem (as dividing by $z$ - or in general by the appropriate power of $z$ so no remaining $w_n$ are zero, $\sum_{|w_n| <r} \log (r/|w_n|)$ is then uniformly bounded so letting $r \to 1$ we get $-\sum \log |w_n|$ bounded but that is of course the same as $\sum (1-|w_n|)$ up to a bounded term etc

Very nice variant using Möbius transformations. Do you think the proof with $F_n(z)$ is also sound?

It kinda of shows explicitly the logarithmic nature of the zero sum so it looks correct
